# mmap() always returns -1

Tags: c, file, mmap

I want to map certain sections of a file into the memory and for this purpose I have to use mmap(). (project reqs)
I open the file with:

```
file = open(fileName, O_RDWR, 0)
```

and it does open regulary (file != -1).

Then, within a for(), I try to map with:

```
char *res;
res = (char*)mmap((void*)sectionHeads[i].adr, sectionHeads[i].size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, file, sectionHeads[i].offset);
```

sectionHead contains adr(int) of the address and so on. But I always get -1 as a result. I checked, and that part of the memory should be free. What am I doing wrong?

note: this is my first time working with mmap(), later on I will think about flags, but right now I just want to map if only one section. Sections contain valid values, double checked that.

update: As suggested I called `perror ("mmap error");` to see what the error is and I get `mmap error: Invalid argument`. Values of adr, size and offset of the first sectionHeads are: adr=8154 size=13 offset=154. I've also thrown out MAP_ANON. What argument is invalid? Is there a way to see that?

Comment: To add to @kirelagin's comment: call `perror()` as soon as you detect that `mmap()` has returned -1 -- i.e., `perror ("mmap error");` -- it will tell you what the error code is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is not checking what exactly is wrong. Upon error, `mmap()` would not only return `MAP_FAILED` (which I recommend you use in place of `-1`), but it also sets `errno` to an appropriate value. So you could either check `errno` yourself or use `perror()` to print the error description which would answer your question as it stands (and save you a lot of time ;)). Aside of that, the use of `MAP_ANONYMOUS` in conjunction with `MAP_SHARED` is only supported on Linux since kernel 2.4; perhaps you have an older version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: I get mmap "error: Invalid argument". My arguments from one of the sectionHeads are:
adr=8154 size=13 offset=154. Also I've thrown out MAP_ANON, as a precaution. Any idea which argument is invalid?

Comment: @InvaderZim: You didn't even read the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), did you? Your offset, for instance, is not a multiple of page size. It is not clear why you need a file if you are creating anonymous mapping. The start of mapping address doesn't look right either... Keep digging.

Comment: I understand the problem with the offset, but why does the address look faulty? Also, is there a way to map bytes from an array? Before I got to the mmap section I read all of the bytes from the file I need. This way I eliminate the offset, and making it the multiple of page size etc.

Comment: @InvaderZim: Well, 8154 is a bit too low for a user-space virtual address. And you cannot really map bytes from the array, unless you actually run in the kernel and have access to MMU and can setup another virtual page mapping that points to the same set of physical addresses. So for the user space program the answer would be no.

Comment: @InvaderZim: In fact, if you are trying to map file contents into memory, pass `NULL` as a first argument and let Linux decide the best address to use. Then pass your size (that is often a size of the file, but could be less) and your offset in multiple of page size (do not hardcode, use [`getpagesize()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html). For flags, just use `MAP_SHARED`.

Comment: I can't pass `NULL` because I'm maping parts of another program that I want to execute later on (no relocation). Thanks for all of the info, it helped me more then 3h of searching the web [: